# HOW TO CREATE A STANDALONE DIV ELEMENT? no toolbars or no favicon of the browser when pop up

Tags: javascript, css, popup, window, draggable

I need a div element which will pop up and can be dragged outside of the browser like a new window.

window.open('#full-width','Tab Heading','height=150,width=150, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, titlebar=no, status=no')

It is draggable but people become to know about it that it's a new pop-up window. But I want to know how I can create A STANDALONE div? no tittle bar, no taskbar button, no tray icon, complete button-free div, minimal GUI footprint.

Comment: You want something that you can drag outside like a new window, but you also want it to be a div inside your page??? not possible, just think it through

Comment: Use an old IE, open a modal/modeless dialog, and set dialog option `unadorned: true`. Your users might need to mark your site as a trusted site in security options in order the make the said option to work.